# AndroidQ DownloadManager.Request.setDestinationUri

Tags: android, android-10.0

My download code stores images that must 'survive' to app uninstall, I used  `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`, but now on Android Q this API is deprecated so I modified my download code

```
val uri = Uri.fromFile(File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "mysubdir"))
val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
.setDestinationUri(uri)
```

to

```
val uri = buildImageUri(context.contentResolver, fileName, fileName)
val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
    .setDestinationUri(uri)

////// Use MediaStore

    fun buildImageUri(
        cr: ContentResolver,
        title: String,
        description: String): Uri? {
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, title)
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, title)
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, description)
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        val buildTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, buildTime)
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, buildTime)

        return cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
    }
```

But I obtain `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file URI: null` so how the code must be written to be Android Q compliant and without using esoteric tricks like search colon in uri and split string?

The documentation for [setDestinationUri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationUri(android.net.Uri)) is not updated and says

> For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above,
>   *omissimis text* or a path within the top-level Downloads directory (as
>   returned by Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String) with
>   Environment#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

Comment: Last I knew, `DownloadManager` did not support `content` `Uri` values, which is what you are trying to use. Unless they make changes, `DownloadManager` is largely useless on Android Q and higher.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are only confirming my suspects... thanks for your reply

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`DownloadManager` still has its long-standing limitation of only supporting `file:` schemes, not `content:`. I filed [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134858946) to try to get this corrected someday.

Your options are:

- Use `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()` on `DownloadManager.Request`, which maps to `getExternalFilesDir()`, which your app has full access to. If the content is something that should survive an app uninstall, you would need to use this as a temporary location and move the content to another, more durable location yourself.
- Use `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` on `DownloadManager.Request`. While the corresponding location (`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`) is deprecated, that does not prevent you from using `DownloadManager` for it. What *may* be a problem is that you will not be able to read or write the downloaded file, as you have no access to this directory, once your app is adopting Android Q's scoped storage. So, this is suitable only for "blind" downloads, where your app is downloading something at user request but only the user (not the app) needs access to the downloaded content.
- Use `setDestinationUri()` on `DownloadManager.Request` for some `file:` `Uri` that represents some other useful location. For example, it is possible (though a bit odd) to want to download to `getExternalCacheDir()`.

Comment: In android Q, DownloadManager `allowScanningByMediaScanner` deprecated. i use `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir` to downloading mp3 file. after completed download, MediaStore does not add song to database. And you have to restart the phone to see song in musics apps such as GoogleMusic , etc. why?

Comment: @Farzad: Given your symptoms, the process behind `DownloadManager` is not telling the `MediaStore` to index the content.

Comment: The interesting thing is that After downloading, songs can be viewed in the `MediaStore` via `LoaderManager`. But `getContentResolver().query()` does not show new indexes. and you have to restart the phone to see. What is the problem? What is the difference between `LoaderManager` and `getContentResolver().query()`? uri It's the same for both: `Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;`

Comment: @Farzad: `LoaderManager` has no means of working with the `MediaStore`. A `CursorLoader` does, and it uses `ContentResolver` and `query()` (see [the `1.1.0` source for `CursorLoader`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/loader/loader/1.1.0-source/androidx/loader/content/CursorLoader.java.html)).

Comment: Unfortunately, you do not understand what I mean. This is a very bad bug in Android 10. I wrote wrong. I mean `LoaderManager`, `CursorLoader`. I use `getContentResolver()` and `CursorLoader` with same `(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)`. result: `getContentResolver()` not found new songs and not exists in mediastore, but `CursorLoader` finded and exists. Android 10 has a very bad performance in the new download indexing :|

Comment: @Farzad: Either there is something in `ContextCompat` that explains your differences, or there is a bug in your testing. `CursorLoader` uses a `ContentResolver`, as you can tell by looking at the source of `CursorLoader` (see my previous comment for the link).

Comment: When CursorLoader is found, it means that the song is indexed in the database. So why not find the song with getContentResolver ()? NOTE! im use same `(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)`