# Download GIF as a file and take it content URI

Tags: android, kotlin, gif

I need to put GIF to input connection https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard.html

But i have a problem because i need to take uri of this GIF. I donwload it like a file and can get only path to it. And how i can get the URI ? Or i need to do this in another way ?

```
Glide.with(this)
            .asFile()
            .load(contentURL)
            .downloadOnly(object: SimpleTarget<File>(){
                override fun onResourceReady(resource: File, transition: Transition<in File>?) {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE (tested)**

**Option 1: Use `Glide`**

```
private suspend fun downloadImage(context: Context, imageUrl: String, fileName: String, folderName: String) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val gifBuffer = Glide.with(context).asGif().load(imageUrl).submit().get().buffer

        val imageUri = getImageUri(getApplication(), fileName, folderName)

        context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(imageUri).use {
            val bytes = ByteArray(gifBuffer.capacity())

            (gifBuffer.clear() as ByteBuffer).get(bytes)    //Both ".clear()" and "as ByteBuffer" are mandatory!!

            it?.write(bytes)
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Use `URL(url).openStream()`**

```
private suspend fun downloadImage(context: Context, imageUrl: String, fileName: String, folderName: String) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val imageUri = getImageUri(getApplication(), fileName, folderName)

        URL(imageUrl).openStream().use { inputStream ->
            context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(imageUri).use { outputStream ->
                inputStream.copyTo(outputStream!!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I think you should use `DownloadManager` to achieve it, which has `setDestinationUri()`.

- Helpful video:
  https://youtu.be/SmXGlv7QEO0?t=642
- Helpful reading:
  https://medium.com/@aungkyawmyint_26195/downloading-file-properly-in-android-d8cc28d25aca

**Remember** to generate the image file `uri` first:

```
private fun getNewImageUri(fileName: String, folderName: String): Uri { //create new file
    val values = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)             //file name
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/gif")             //file type
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "${Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD}/$folderName")     //file location
    }

    return requireContext().contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)!!
}
```

Comment: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media

Comment: @Serhii Bilotserkovets Which step?

Comment: `Remember to generate the image file uri first:` That makes no sense as DownloadManager does not accept content scheme uries.

Comment: @blackapps You're right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487929/androidq-downloadmanager-request-setdestinationuri